Change billing and shipping editable fields in WooCommerce admin order pages
I've created a custom form-billing.php file where there are some custom fields:

billing_name (instead of billing_first_name and billing_last_name),
shipping_name (instead of shipping_first_name and shipping_last_name)

I made these fiels with a custom function in functions.php:
function custom_override_shipping_fields($fields) {
    
    unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_first_name']);
    unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_last_name']);
    unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_address_2']);

    unset($fields['billing']['billing_first_name']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_last_name']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_2']);

    unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_country']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_country']);

    unset($fields['billing']['billing_email']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_phone']);

    $fields['contact'] = array(
        'contact_heading' => array(
            'type' => 'heading',
            'label' => __('Dane kontaktowe', 'text-domain'),
            'class' => array('form-row-wide'), // Klasy CSS
            'required' => false,
        ),
    );

    $fields['contact']['billing_email'] = array(
        'type'          => 'email',
        'label'         => __('Adres email', 'text-domain'),
        'placeholder'   => __('Podaj adres email', 'text-domain'),
        'required'      => true,
        'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'         => true,
        'priority'      => 10,
    );

    $fields['contact']['billing_phone'] = array(
        'type'          => 'tel',
        'label'         => __('Adres email', 'text-domain'),
        'placeholder'   => __('Podaj adres email', 'text-domain'),
        'required'      => true,
        'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'         => true,
        'priority'      => 20,
    );

    $fields['billing']['billing_name'] = array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'label'         => __('Imię i nazwisko', 'text-domain'),
        'placeholder'   => __('Podaj imię i nazwisko', 'text-domain'),
        'required'      => true,
        'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'         => true,
        'priority'      => 10,
    );

    $fields['billing']['billing_company'] = array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'label'         => __('Nazwa firmy', 'text-domain'),
        'placeholder'   => __('Podaj nazwę firmy', 'text-domain'),
        'required'      => false,
        'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'         => true,
        'priority'      => 20,
    );

    $fields['billing']['billing_company_nip'] = array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'label'         => __('NIP firmy', 'text-domain'),
        'placeholder'   => __('Podaj NIP firmy', 'text-domain'),
        'required'      => false,
        'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'         => true,
        'priority'      => 30,
    );

    $fields['billing']['billing_address_1'] = array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'label'         => __('Ulica, nr domu/lokalu', 'text-domain'),
        'placeholder'   => __('Podaj ulicę i nr domu/lokalu', 'text-domain'),
        'required'      => true,
        'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'         => true,
        'priority'      => 40,
    );

    $fields['billing']['billing_postcode'] = array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'label'         => __('Kod pocztowy', 'text-domain'),
        'placeholder'   => __('Podaj kod pocztowy', 'text-domain'),
        'required'      => true,
        'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'         => true,
        'priority'      => 50,
    );

    $fields['billing']['billing_city'] = array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'label'         => __('Miejscowość', 'text-domain'),
        'placeholder'   => __('Podaj miejscowość', 'text-domain'),
        'required'      => true,
        'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'         => true,
        'priority'      => 60,
    );

    $fields['shipping']['shipping_name'] = array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'label'         => __('Imię i nazwisko', 'text-domain'),
        'placeholder'   => __('Podaj imię i nazwisko', 'text-domain'),
        'required'      => true,
        'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'         => true,
        'priority'      => 10,
    );

    $fields['shipping']['shipping_company'] = array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'label'         => __('Nazwa firmy', 'text-domain'),
        'placeholder'   => __('Podaj nazwę firmy', 'text-domain'),
        'required'      => false,
        'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'         => true,
        'priority'      => 20,
    );

    $fields['shipping']['shipping_address_1'] = array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'label'         => __('Ulica, nr domu/lokalu', 'text-domain'),
        'placeholder'   => __('Podaj ulicę, nr domu/lokalu', 'text-domain'),
        'required'      => true,
        'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'         => true,
        'priority'      => 30,
    );

    $fields['shipping']['shipping_postcode'] = array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'label'         => __('Kod pocztowy', 'text-domain'),
        'placeholder'   => __('Podaj kod pocztowy', 'text-domain'),
        'required'      => true,
        'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'         => true,
        'priority'      => 40,
    );

    $fields['shipping']['shipping_city'] = array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'label'         => __('Miejscowość', 'text-domain'),
        'placeholder'   => __('Podaj miejscowość', 'text-domain'),
        'required'      => true,
        'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
        'clear'         => true,
        'priority'      => 50,
    );
    

    return $fields;
}

Now I need to edit WooCommerce order editor to match the fields I've created in checkout form. I tried similar approach using woocommerce_admin_order_data_billing_fields hook but it didn't work. I simply cannot get rid of these fields.

